# Jackson: Parse same key with different model

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, fasterxml

In Kotlin, I'm using jackson (fasterxml) for parsing an endpoint response (JSON). It looks similar to this:

```
{
...
steps: [
   {
      "status":200,
      "id":"A",
      "data":{
         "score":"10"
      }
   },
   {
      "status":200,
      "id":"B",
      "data": {
         "dateOfBirth":"10-09-1994",
         "fullname": "Peter",
         ...
      }
   },
   {
      "status":200,
      "id":"C",
      "data": {
         "dateOfBirth": {
             "value": "10-03-1993"
          },
         ...
      }
   },
]
...
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
...
response.readEntity(DocumentResponse::class.java)
...



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class DocumentResponse @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("steps")
    val steps: List<StepResponse>
) 

data class StepResponse @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("status")
    val status: String,
    @JsonProperty("id")
    val id: String,
    @JsonProperty("data")
    val data: Data?
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Data @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")
    val dateOfBirth: String?,
    @JsonProperty("fullName")
    val fullName: String?,
    @JsonProperty("dni")
    val dni: String?,
    ...
)
```

The problem is that `data` can have multiple types, and **I want to get this field from the JSON only when id is "B"**. When the JSON is retrieved and it's read, an error is thrown because it reads step with id "A" and `dateOfBirth` is not found, so it throws the following error:

**MistmatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of string out of START_OBJECT token ...**

Is possible to ignore the field `data` if it doesn't match with the JSON format?
I want to read the JSON but the only `data` that is relevant to me is the one related to a specific id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your best option is to use a custom deserializer for `StepResponse`:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

class StepResponseDeserializer constructor(vc: Class<*>? = null) : StdDeserializer<StepResponse>(vc) {
    override fun deserialize(jp: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): StepResponse {
        val node = jp.codec.readTree<JsonNode>(jp)
        val status = node["status"].asText()
        val id = node["id"].asText()

        val data = if ("B" == id) {
            val dataNode = node["data"]
            val dateOfBirth = dataNode["status"].asText()
            val fullName = dataNode["fullName"].asText()
            val dni = dataNode["dni"].asText()
            Data(dateOfBirth, fullName, dni)
        } else null

        return StepResponse(status, id, data)
    }
}
```

You can register the deserializer directly on the class as follows:

```kotlin
@JsonDeserialize(using = StepResponseDeserializer.class)
data class StepResponse @JsonCreator constructor(
    val status: String,
    val id: String,
    val data: Data?
)
```

As a side note, you can drop all the `@JsonProperty` annotations given that they are only needed if the Java/Kotlin property name does not match the JSON property name.

Comment: Glad I could help!